# Detect & Convert encoding for broken file names

Tags: encoding, filename

I downloaded some mp3 files that has Japanese character in its name and now the file name is broken. I tired `convmv` to convert encoding, but i cannot seem to find in which encoding the filename is written.  Can anyone help me to detect filename encoding and convert it to UTF-8?